# Replace elements of a list if the conditional is false

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

There is a list:

```
{1, {a, b, c}, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {A, B, D, Z}}
```

It contains sublists of different elements and several $1$s.  The goal is to replace an element to $0$ if it's not $1$.

Desirable outcome:

```
{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}.
```

I know that there is a replace all (/.) function that can do such work but can't find out how to apply it here. What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Replace[
 {1, {a, b, c}, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {A, B, D, Z}},
 Except[1] :> 0,
 1
 ]
```

where the third argument of `Replace` contrains the application of the replacement rule to the 1st level of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, {a, b, c}, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {A, B, D, Z}};
```

There will be lots of ways of doing this, but here is one.

```
If[# === 1, 1, 0] & /@ list
(* {1, 0, 1, 0, 0} *)
```

(Solving this using pattern matching is made more difficult by the need to avoid matching the whole list).

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, {a, b, c}, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {A, B, D, Z}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Flatten @ SequenceSplit[list, {_List} :> 0]
```

{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> 0, Position[list, _?VectorQ]] @ list
```

{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, {a, b, c}, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {A, B, D, Z}};
```

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list, Position[list, x_List, 1] -> 0]

(*{1, 0, 1, 0, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`"];
lis = {1, {a, b, c}, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {A, B, D, Z}}

# # === # & /@ lis // Boole
```

or

```
Boole[# # === #] & /@ lis
```

---

*Result:*

> {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}